# Functions between Sets of different Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\alpha : A \to B$ be a function between finite sets. Show that if $|A| > |B|$, then $α$ cannot be injective, and if $|A| < |B|$, then $α$ cannot be surjective .

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $\alpha$ injective with $|A|>|B|$. Then, $\forall b \in B$, $\alpha^{-1}(b)$ must have $0$ or $1$ element. Then, $|A|=|\alpha^{-1}(B)|\leq|B|$, what is a contradiction.

Suppose we have $\alpha$ surjective with $|A|<|B|$. Then $\forall b \in B$, $\alpha^{-1}(b)$ must have at least $1$ element. Then, $|A|=|\alpha^{-1}(B)|\geq|B|$, what is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $|A|>|B|$ then at least one element in $B$ is being mapped to more than once, so $\alpha$ is not injective. If $|A|<|B|$ then at least one element in $B$ is not being mapped to at all, so $\alpha$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework - I'll do the injective case and leave the surjective case up to you.

A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ maps every element in $A$ to exactly one element in $B$, though the elements that are mapped to are not necessarily all distinct - we say that a function is injective if they are.

If $|A| > |B|$, then even if every element of $A$ corresponds to exactly one distinct element of $B$, we know from the pigeonhole principle that there will be elements in $B$ without a corresponding element in $A$. Thus, $f$ is not injective.